# Testing Google Apps Script web app with QUnit

Tags: google-apps-script, testing, web-applications, qunit

I have a Google Apps Script web app, that previously worked, but when I tried to add some code to the "server-side", it broke the app. I wish to go back in and do some unit testing and possibly a bit of regression testing (even though my manual regression testing just failed), on the different functions and modules of this app.

I stumbled upon [this library for GAS unit testing](https://github.com/simula-innovation/qunit/tree/gas/gas) and a [tutorial for using the library](http://www.tothenew.com/blog/how-to-test-google-apps-script-using-qunit/). Problem is that, to actually see the results of the test, you must implement a `function doGet(e)` for testing.

This app I'm trying to unit-test, being a web app, already has that function. Its implementation is as follows:

```
function doGet(e) {
  return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile(
    'potholeMap'
  ).evaluate()
   .setTitle('Pothole Map')
   .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME);
}
```

When I bring in the QUnit library dependency, and refactor it to allow QUnit testing, such as below:

```
function doGet(e) {
    var TESTING = true; 
    if (TESTING)
    {
        QUnit.urlParams(e.parameter);
        QUnit.load(function test() {});
        return QUnit.getHtml();
    }

    return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile(
        'potholeMap'
    ).evaluate()
        .setTitle('Pothole Map')
        .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME);
}
```

I get this error when I try to run it: `Authorization is required to perform that action.` How do I fix this so that I can do unit testing in the project, as well as run it as web app?

Comment: Try running the doGet() function from the Script Window: Run > Run Function > doGet. That should get a window to popup to authorize the scopes you use in the script.

Comment: Running any function from the project should be sufficient to prompt the authorization flow

Comment: I get the following error upon trying to run the `doGet()`: `TypeError: Cannot read property "parameter" from undefined. (line 6, file "Code")`
right on the line where I use `QUnit`

Comment: nevermind. I figured it out...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't know that, when I add library, I have to re-authorize the code. That is done via running a function, clicking the button with text like "Authorize", and following the popup prompt to authorize the app. (If only I knew how to verify this app, but that is another question...)

Answer (score 1):

Check out [QUnitGS2](http://qunitgs2.com/) - a new Apps Script library using the latest version of QUnit (v2.10.1).

There are instructions on how to run the tests alongside an existing web app by creating your own router using the query string.